# Finding an inherited entity over a jointable with NamedQuery

Tags: jpa, multiple-inheritance, join, named-query

How can I use a NamedQuery to find an entity over a jointable?
I have an abstract parent class/entity with @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED) and two subclasses/subentities.
Hence, in the database I have a parent table (*sdrs*) and two subtables (*xSdrs* and *ySdrs*). 
There is another table *reservations* which shall have a Many-to-Many relationship to table *sdrs*. That's why I created a jointable between *reservations* and *sdrs*. 

I intend to have a *NamedQuery* in the parent entity *Sdr* to be able to find the key for a record/entity of *XSdr* or *YSdr* respectively over the jointable.

In class *Sdr* I have:

```
@NamedQuery(name="Sdr.findBySdrId", query="SELECT s FROM Sdr s "
            + "INNER JOIN s.reservations res WHERE res.sdrs = :transactionId")
```

and

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="sdrs_has_reservations",  
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name="sdrs_id", referencedColumnName="sdrId", nullable=false)
        }, inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="reservations_id", referencedColumnName="reservationId", nullable=false)
        })
private List<Reservation<T>> reservations;
```

But, of course, this sets the *transactionId* to *reservationId* which consequentially fails.

On the inverse side I have:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="reservations", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Sdr<T>> sdrs;
```

So, how do I have to implement the named query in class/entity Sdr to be able to get the proper Sdr (and its related reservations) with an Sdr ID to be set as query parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT sdr FROM Reservation r JOIN r.sdrs sdr WHERE sdr.id=:id

Comment: Sometimes it can be so easy! Thank you. :-D